# Cloudformation: update stack error Service: ElastiCache, Status Code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Im using cdk to to create a stack with a redis cluster

```js
const subnets = vpc.privateSubnets.map(subnet => subnet.subnetId);
       const subnetGroups = new CfnSubnetGroup(
            this,
            'redisSubnets',
            {
                description: 'redis-subnets-${environmentName}',
                subnetIds: subnets
            }
        );
        new RedisLogs(
            this,
            'redisClusterLogs',
            environmentName
        );

        const logsDeliveryConfiguration: CfnCacheCluster.LogDeliveryConfigurationRequestProperty = {
            logFormat: 'json',
            logType: 'slow-log',
            destinationDetails: {
                cloudWatchLogsDetails: {
                    logGroup: `/redis/${environmentName}`
                }
            },
            destinationType: 'cloudwatch-logs'
        };

        const clusterProps: CfnCacheClusterProps = {
            cacheNodeType: 'cache.t3.micro',
            engine: 'redis',
            numCacheNodes: 1,
            autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,
            vpcSecurityGroupIds: [securityGroup.securityGroupId],
            cacheSubnetGroupName: subnetGroups.ref,
            clusterName: `cluster-${environmentName}`,
            logDeliveryConfigurations: [logsDeliveryConfiguration],
            engineVersion: "6.2"
        };

        this.redisCluster = new CfnCacheCluster(
            this,
            'redis-cluster',
            clusterProps
        );

        this.redisCluster.addDependsOn(subnetGroups)
```

cloudformation fails with this error into resource redisSubnets:

```
Resource handler returned message: "No modifications were requested. (Service: ElastiCache, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxxxxx)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

Im using the same code for develop, certification environments, only in test environment causes this error

im trying update a large stack that contains several nested stacks, like fargate cluster, ec2 security groups, rds and elasticache-redis

The redis stack not have any change, but cloudformation fails here